# how to get the result of a mysql prepared query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, return-value

I am using the php prepared statement to query a table to see if the given value is in a column. However i cannot seem to get a result out of the prepared query. I can get whether or not the query happened successfully but not the results from that query.

```
$write = $DB_Connection->prepare("SELECT * from Table where Column = ?");

$result = $write->bind_param('s', $Value);
```

I have tried

```
$write->fetch();
mysqli_stmt_fetch($write);
```

but these do not give me useful results. I cannot use `get->results` as its not mysqlnd

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to execute the query after preparing and binding:

```
// execute statement
$resultset = $write->execute();

// grab data, eg., like this
$result = $resultset->fetch_all();
```

Besides you should check for errors somewhere as well.

- [MySQLi execute](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php)